# Natural remedies to get rid of flies (Housefly)

Tags: home, personal-care, health

I'm really got fed up with these irritating buzzing flies all over my house. What is a natural way to repel or otherwise get rid of the flies?

Comment: Place well readable signs all around your house saying `Here Be Frogs`.

Comment: Start by putting fly nets on all windows and doors which are usually open. We live in an agricultural area and this is what keeps us sane.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if most people knew about this remedy to avoid houseflies already.

**Using plastic water bags to keep away flies.**

My friend has a grocery store and I have seen him hanging half filled plastic water bags on the entrance of the store. I didn't know the reason behind this until now but after searching about it I got this.

[image: plastic water bags]

There are at least two reasons explained for this remedy which seems to be beyond logic. One is that the flies are not able to see the water bag as a water bag. Due to their structure of eyes, clear water filled bags are seen as something resembling a spider’s web by the flies. As such, they don’t come near such a thing. The other reason states that the reflection of water is enough to disorient the flies and to create some inexplicable illusion to them.

**Get this**:

Clear plastic bag (gallon size)-1

Water

**Do this**:

Fill the plastic bag with water. Keep it halfway full with water.

Tie a knot at the mouth of the bag to secure it properly. You may also use a thread or a rubber band for the purpose.

Now just hang this water filled plastic bags near your entryways, garage doors or any other such outdoor entrance.

**Advantages**:

- doesn't harm any housefly; only keeps them away.
- doesn't use any harmful chemical.
- cheap

Source: [Google](http://google.com)

Comment: Me too. Thanks for this lifehacks; in (& around) our family cottage on the mountain there is a lot of flies.

Comment: I saw it used against cats and against pigeons. It sure doesn't work against pigeons, don't know about cats, I bet it doesn't work against them, either. I want to try it against houseflies to see how it doesn't work against them, too. Sadly, I have no houseflies :(

Answer (score 4):

I have myself gone through the same problem last year. So, as per my personal experiences, I will suggest you few methods:

- **Using Carnivorous Plants:** Adding a few carnivorous plants such as Venus Fly Trap or pitcher plant near the infested area can also help in controlling the fly infestation. They are slow but they work.

[image: Venus Fly Trap]

- **Using Lavender Oil Repellents:** Lavender helps to control the infestation of flies along with repelling fleas, black fly, black beetle, greenfly and whitefly too. To make the repellent:

1. Dip a cloth or a sponge in the lavender oil.
2. Next, place this cloth or sponge in the tin can, put on the lid and leave it for 24 hours.
3. After 24 hours, remove the lid and keep the tin at a place where you see most of the flies in your home. You will see that flies will be repelled by the lavender fragrance.

- **Lemongrass Spray:** Lemongrass oil is one of few sprays that flies hate the most. You can pour 10 -15 drops of lemongrass oil in a spray bottle. After this put 2 cups of warm water in the spray bottle. Shake the mixture well and spray over the infested areas.
- **Herbs that can help you to get rid of flies:** Flies hate certain herbs like Basil, Lavender, Bay Leaf, Tansy, Mint, Rue, and Wormwood. If you plant these herbs in the infested area you will see that flies leave the area quickly.
- **Camphor to Repel Flies:** Camphor has a strong smell that deters flies and other insects. It has been traditionally used in India to purify the surrounding environment as it has strong antibacterial, anti-viral, and insect repellent properties. It is commercially available in form of small tablets. Take 2 camphor tablets and place it on a warm surface near the infested areas. This works like a charm.

[image: Bug-A-Salt]

- **A fun way to kill flies:** Bug-A-Salt looks pretty much like an “assault rifle”, the rifle uses regular table salt to shoot a concentrated spray pattern of salt granules (very much like a shotgun), killing the flies and other flying insects on contact.
  The salt used in the gun would not damage your walls or furniture but it is strong enough to easily kill flies. This fly rifle is a non-toxic, battery-free device that allows you to have fun while getting rid of flies.

There are many such other methods mentioned on [www.fliesonly.com](http://www.getridoffliesguide.com).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a good one where you take a water bottle and cut it in half.  Then take the top half, invert it, and place it into the bottom half.  Place a small amount of beer/juice/etc. in the bottom.  The flies will go in and will often not be able to escape.

Comment: Our flies wouldn't be too interested in that bait. Wasps otoh and fruit flies would.

Comment: I'll try it. Maybe is good to coat bottle (with some nice decorative paper), to avoid view on flies. :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting some of the plants and materials flies hate around a home tends to work. They cannot strong-smelling plants like basil and lavender, but essential oils like Eucalyptus and Lavender also work great. Orange peels also contain the citrus flies hat and can be used to the same effect along with any camphor you have.

Answer (score 0):

Get a strip of paper and coat it with a sticky substance (glue/resin) that does not dry out for a dew days. Hang a couple of these sticky strips from your ceiling with thumbtacks and some string.

Flies will randomly land on them, get permanently stuck and perish. After a few days, take down the strips and throw them away. In my country you can just buy these strips rolled up in little canisters, coated with some extremely sticky resin.

They are completely non-toxic, so as far as I am concerned this is a "natural" solution.